# Properties of grupoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We had this on our midterm test yesterday and I still can't find anyone reliable who solved it, so I can compare my solution. I have read the policies about asking questions here and I know that I already provided solution (which can be wrong), but I hope that I don't fall under any of those banned categories and if so, I am willing to risk it, because I don't know any other place to ask this kind of question.

Let's say I have monoid of functions $f: \mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{I}$ ($\mathbb{I}$ denotes set of irrational numbers) with binary operation of function composition $\circ$ and let's take $M = \{f(x) = \frac{x}{1 + ax}, a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ as its subset. Prove whether $\mathbb{I}$ is closed under the operation $\circ$ on grupoid $(M,\circ)$. Also prove whether this grupoid is

1. Semigroup
2. Commutative semigroup
3. Monoid
4. Commutative monoid
5. Group
6. Commutative group

I have proven the closure property of $\circ$ like this. Let's assume $f(x) = \frac{x}{1 + ax}$, $g(x) = \frac{x}{1 + bx}$. Then $(g \circ f)(x)$, or also $g(f(x))$, equals to $\frac{x}{1 + (a+b)x}$. Since $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $(a+b) \in \mathbb{Z}$, so we can assume that also the image of $x$ is irrational. I am not sure with this one, but whenever I imagine $\sqrt{2}$ or $\pi$ in place of $x$, I can't see how to get rational number because of $1$ in denominator.

Semigroup requires associative law to apply on $\circ$, which is fairly easy to prove so I am not going to write it here.

Commutative semigroup requires commutative law to apply on $\circ$, and because $g(f(x)) = \frac{x}{1 + (a+b)x}$, then $f(g(x)) = \frac{x}{1 + (b+a)x}$ so commutativity applies and $(M,\circ)$ is commutative semigroup.

Monoid requires existence of identity element. So we need to find such $e(x)$ that holds $e(f(x)) = f(e(x)) = f(x)$. This can be rewritten as $\frac{x}{1+(c+a)x} = \frac{x}{1+ax}$, so $c = 0$ and therefore $e(x) = \frac{x}{1+0x} = x$. Commutativity is inherited from semigroup.

Group requires existence of inverse element for every $f$, denoted $f^{-1}$. Therefore, there must be $a^{-1}$ such that holds $\frac{x}{1+(a+a^{-1})x} = x$. Then, $a^{-1} = -a$ and because $-a \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{1-ax}$. Commutativity is again inherited from monoid.

Can someone please verify my solution? Did I do anything wrong? If so, could you please explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like solid work to me. The part where you didn't know if $f(x)$ was always irrational was already given. Since $M$ was given to be a subset of all functions $\mathbb{I}\to\mathbb{I}$.  To see that $x\mapsto \frac{x}{1+ax}$ does indeed map irrationals to irrationals you can observe that it is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{-1}{a}\}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{1}{a}\}$ that maps rationals to rationals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, at least I have it confirmed now. Thanks again.